# Merchant Review Invitation Error already exists: 104404271 error on new order shipment

Tags: magento2, new-shipment

I am facing issues while generating new shipment admin order. Please check below image.

[image]

Anybody have any idea about it ?

Comment: Did you solve this? I think we've had the issue since launch but we've labelled as a Low Priority fix. To be honest, I assumed it was an API message from a 3rd party review service we use. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @Craig not yet. But this errors coming from "Reviewscouk_Reviews" module.

Comment: That's what we use. I figured as much because the message text cannot be found on the server itself, so concluded it was an API push message. It hasn't broken anything for us, it's just a bit of an eye-sore. You'll want Revews.co.uk to fix their plugin/API. Good luck with that :)